# PHP counter with flock

Tags: php, flock

I have a problem with a counter. I need to count two variables, separated with a `|`, but sometimes the counter doesn't increase a variable's value.

numeri.txt (the counter):

```
6122|742610
```

This is the PHP script:

```
$filename="numeri.txt";
while(!$fp=fopen($filename,'c+'))
{
    usleep(100000);
}
while(!flock($fp,LOCK_EX))
{
    usleep(100000);
}
$contents=fread($fp,filesize($filename));
ftruncate($fp,0);
rewind($fp);
$contents=explode("|",$contents);
$clicks=$contents[0];
$impressions=$contents[1]+1;
fwrite($fp,$clicks."|".$impressions);
flock($fp,LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

I have another counter that is a lot slower but counts both values (clicks and impressions) exactly. Sometimes the counter `numeri.txt` counts more impressions than the other counter. Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Check whether the second while loops runs into a max_execution timeout, i reckon sime kind of deadlock/starvation scenario.

Comment: When you say "sometimes" - Do you mean that sometime the function increases and sometimes it doesn't? Or do you mean that some rows arent affected each time?

Comment: I mean that the function increases, but more than how it should increase

Comment: @mightyuhu how can i check it?

Comment: Ok. Does the numeri.txt ONLY contain those two values?

Comment: Yes, it is like i wrote it

6122|742610

Comment: Shouldn't it be $clicks=$contents[0]+1; ?

Comment: no he wants to increase the 2nd value

Comment: take a look in your php error log (if you have one)
you may provoke this by using apache bench command

`$ab -n 1000 -c 200 http://localhost/your.php`

Comment: @mightyuhu - Ok. But I read "I need to count two variables, separated with a |" in the question... ...so it's not obvious. AND "I have another counter that is a lot slower but counts both value"

Comment: another file counts the clicks, this counts the impressions.

Comment: @mightyuhu I don't have any error log. What should I do?

Comment: maybe its the other script? can you provide it?

Comment: it's the same, but it has `$clicks=$contents[0]+1;$impressions=$contents[1];` instead of `$clicks=$contents[0];$impressions=$contents[1]+1;`, in order to add the first value (clicks)

Answer (score 1):

We're using the following at our high-traffic site to count impressions:

```
<?php

    $countfile = "counter.txt"; // SET THIS

    $yearmonthday = date("Y.m.d");
    $yearmonth = date("Y.m");;

    // Read the current counts
    $countFileHandler = fopen($countfile, "r+");
    if (!$countFileHandler) {
        die("Can't open count file");
    }

    if (flock($countFileHandler, LOCK_EX)) {
        while (($line = fgets($countFileHandler)) !== false) {
            list($date, $count) = explode(":", trim($line));
            $counts[$date] = $count;
        }

        $counts[$yearmonthday]++;
        $counts[$yearmonth]++;

        fseek($countFileHandler, 0);

        // Write the counts back to the file
        krsort($counts);
        foreach ($counts as $date => $count) {
            fwrite($countFileHandler, "$date:$count\n");
            fflush($countFileHandler);
        }

        flock($countFileHandler, LOCK_UN);
    } else {
        echo "Couldn't acquire file lock!";
    }

    fclose($countFileHandler);
}
?>
```

The results are both daily and monthly totals:

```
2015.10.02:40513
2015.10.01:48396
2015.10:88909
```

Answer (score 0):

Try performing a flush before unlocking. You're unlocking before the data might even be written, allowing another execution to clobber.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php

Comment: I added `fflush($fp);` between `fwrite` and `flock($fp,LOCK_UN);` but it's still not working... It counts 1 value more

Comment: What do you mean "counts 1 value more".